# Questions about adjoint functions

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V, W$ be euclidean vector spaces and $f \in \mathrm {Hom}_{\mathbb {R}}(V,W)$. The adjoint function of $f$ is $f^{ad} \in \mathrm {Hom}_{\mathbb {R}}(W,V)$. Which of these following statements is true?

a. $f$ is surjective iff $f^{ad}$ is surjective.

b. $f$ is injective iff $f^{ad}$ is injective.

c. $f$ is surjective iff $f^{ad}$ is injective.

d. $f^{ad}$ is surjective iff $f$ is injective.

Can someone help me with this? I'm not sure at all.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Only c,d are true. To prove c, we can begin one approach by noting that
$$
f^{\text{ad}}(y) = 0 \iff \text{for all }x \in V, \langle x, f^{\text{ad}}(y) \rangle = 0.
$$